# Сборка под Linux, си

Tags: c, linux

В чем суть, есть сырцы программы, и в них мне нужно вставить свой код
Рассмотрю на простом примере

1. Беру программу (к примеру Postgis)
2. вставляю в Postgis свою функцию, а именно хедер и функцию `__memset_probe(newpoints, size)`.

   ```
   // Код программы Postgis
   #include <VulLib/vullib.h>// подключаю свою библиотеку

   //...
   {__memset_probe(newpoints, size); memset(newpoints, 0, size);}
   //...
   ```
3. кладу свою папу VulLib с хедером и сишником сюда - `/usr/include/VulLib`

   vullib.c

   ```
   #include "vullib.h"
   void *__memset_probe(void *s, size_t count)
   {
   // делает что то, например выводит сообщение в опр. файл    
   return s;
   }
   ```

   vullib.h

   ```
   #ifndef __VULLIB__
   #define __VULLIB__

   #include <stdio.h>
   void *__memset_probe(void *, size_t);
   #endif /* __VULLIB__ */
   ```
4. Собираю программу (Postgis)

   ```
   ./configure 
   make
   ```

но выдает следующую ошибку:

```
more undefined references to `__memset_probe' follow
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Подскажи те что делать, вроде бы там нужно в makefile указать что еще нужно, но для меня это все темный лес
распишите подробней.

Comment: Думаю, более полный вывод make поможет понять в чем проблема.

Answer (score 1):

Судя по выводу, не скомпилировался vullib.c
попробуйте добавить vullib.c в директорию с исходниками Postgis и опять запустить configure и make

**Update**
Make файл генерится после того как вы запускаете configure. Если нужно добавить не большое кол-во .c файлов и это будет однократно, то после запуска configure можно поправить сгенеренный Make файл. Найдите, где в Postgis лежит Makefile, и найдите в тексте, где добавлены .c файлы, добавьте ваши файлы по аналогии, далее запустите make.
Если более постоянное решение, то нужно править configure.ac

Comment: попробовал, снова такая же проблема, и да вы правы, он не видет vullib.c, но вот как сделать так что бы увидел, я без понятия

Comment: Makefile смотреть, что же еще?

Comment: Дело в том, что вот эти функции __memset_probe(newpoints, size) я вставил во всю программу Postgis,
перед каждым вызовом функции memset. То есть их достаточно много
Но при сборке компилятор ругается данной ошибкой
more undefined references to `__memset_probe' follow
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
лишь на одни файл, а касательно остальных, то он видит что они обьявлены

И вот в чем вопрос, от чего это зависит?! уже все перепробовал

Comment: Для начала, наверное проще всего положить Ваш `vullib.c` вместе с родными .c, посмотреть в Makefile что-то вроде SRCS = .... и добавить к ним vullib.c

Comment: @Дмитрий, обновил ответ. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoconf